# What is wrong with this ettercap dump file?

Tags: linux, sniffing, ettercap

I am trying to read a dump file which is created with ettercap. But when I am trying to read it with ettercap it is saying:
Error while capturing: bogus savefile header
And I can't read the file with tcpdump or wireshark either. What is wrong with it?

Comment: How did you save the files? When you use Ettercap -L it will generate `ecp` files which are not in tcpdump (pcap) format. You must use `ettercap -w` to generate pcap,format.

Comment: It looks like the dump file is corrupted somehow.